# Excel Vlookup or Query

Tags: excel, vlookup

Hi wonder if someone can help?

I have two spreadsheets,
One has 4 columns, part number in A,  Description in  B, Cost 1 in C and Cost 2 in D

In the second spreadsheet I want to type in the part number in column A and it search the second spreadsheet for the part number  in column A then compare cost1 (B) and cost2 (b) and the return the lower (cheapest) value.

Is this possible?

Thanks

Comment: Just do a Google search on how Vlookup works.  That's pretty much what it's for.

Comment: Yes, sounds possible.

Answer (score 0):

you can either use this array formula:

```
=MIN(VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet1!A:D,{3,4},FALSE))
```

Being an array formula it needs to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-enter instead of Enter when exiting Edit mode.  If done correctly then Excel will put `{}` around the formula.

Or you can split the Vlookups and enter it normally:

```
=MIN(VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet1!A:D,3,FALSE),VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet1!A:D,4,FALSE))
```

[image]